# In php, how to make the first input value always be smaller than the second input value?

Tags: php, html

In php file, I have these two text place to let the user to type in 2 numbers, and I want to alert something when the first input is bigger than the second input. Should use gmp_cmp to do that? Really appreciate it.

```
    <input type="text" name="min" placeholder="min" size="6" maxlength="2" required>
    to<input type="text" name="max" placeholder="max" size="6" maxlength="2" required>
```

Comment: Have you written any code to do this yet?

Comment: No. I tried to use the gmp_cmp, but it shows the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe the best way it's check with Jquery, but if you need with PHP:

```
<?php //Estrutural
$min = $_POST[min];
$max = $_POST[max];
if($min > $max){
   echo "Min value must be smaller than max value";
}else{
    echo "do something";
}
?>
```

But best way is Jquery, this way user doesn't will know before form submit that something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should in php to catch the values of the input min and max and a IF condition for determinate it. As you are using numbers, you have to use an type="number" in the `<input>` Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="file.php">
    <input type="number" name="min" placeholder="min" required>
    <input type="number" name="max" placeholder="max" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Check the size"> 
</form>

<?php 

    //FILE.PHP
    $min = $_POST['min'];
    $max = $_POST['max'];
    //IF MIN = 10 AND MAX = 5, ALERT TO USER
    if ( $min > $max  ) {
        echo 'You cant do that';
    }

    else {
        echo 'Correct!';
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery way in which the clicking of the check button compares the two values and alerts if the max is less than the min. It also then clears out the max value and resets focus to it.

```js
$('#checkValue').on('click',function(){
 var min=parseInt($('[name=min]').val());
 var max=parseInt($('[name=max]').val());

 if(max < min)
  { alert('error: the maximum value cannot be less than the minimum value');
   $('[name=max]').val('').focus()
  }
 })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
 <form>
   <input type="text" name="min" placeholder="min" size="6" maxlength="2" required>
  to <input type="text" name="max" placeholder="max" size="6" maxlength="2" required>
  <button type ="button" id="checkValue">Check Value</button>
 </form>
 <p id="result"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```